# Which Script Loaders(AMD or not) for using with Backbone.js/Underscore?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

For a week i started learning how to use require.js with **Backbone.js** and **Underscore.js**.

It's a really difficult stuff, but 3 days ago i read that Underscore will not supporting **Require.js(AMD)** anymore! Now i'm a bit confuse.

I really like the Concept of Script Loader and dont want to miss it!

Have someone already successfully used a Script Loader with Backbone.js(0.5.3) and Underscore(1.3.0)?

Thank you for helping!

**Link :** another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution which really work for me  : [Tim Brayen](http://tbranyen.com/post/amdrequirejs-shim-plugin-for-loading-incompatible-javascript)

```
define([
'jquery',
'use!underscore',
'use!backbone',
```

I use it to add jquery plugin, custom js , underscore and backbone( without changing the code!)... but it seems to have a problem with jquery mobile...

you can also take a look to [wrap](https://github.com/geddesign/wrap.js), i have not tested it yet!

Comment: Could you file an issue in the GitHub repo if there is still an issue with jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using underscore 1.3 and Backbone 0.5.3 in my Backbone Boilerplate.  You can see what I'm doing there:

https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate

Comment: @CMP because its been merged into master, comment is updated.

Answer (score 2):

you can still make underscore work with require.js even though it does not natively supports AMD module style.

you can still load it as a normal external javascript source, through a proxy module.

the gist of it is this piece of code:

```
// Filename: libs/underscore/underscore
// Loads the original underscore file from the libs/underscore folder
define(['order!libs/underscore/underscore-min'], function(){
  // Tell Require.js that this module returns a reference to Underscore
  return _;
});
```

the full tutorial can be found here: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Comment: I try it! but unfortunaly i'm actually working with the last stable version of underscore(1.3.0)! and Thomas Davis uses Underscore.js 1.1.7!!

Comment: take a look at this thread on github, AMD support removed in underscore 1.3.0 but still possible through a proxy or shim like i said, https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/commit/0d4b1247c45083c695cab4242c084a97aa600221#commitcomment-857941... So it really should still be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few here as well...

https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter
https://github.com/jcreamer898/Savefavs

**UPDATE July 7/08/2012**

The latest version of RequireJS allows NON-AMD compliant libraries with the following code.

```
require.config({ 
    'paths': { 
    "underscore": "libs/underscore-min", 
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-min"
    },
    'shim': 
    {
        backbone: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jcreamer! but you use Underscore.js 1.2.2 isn't? my application already run with underscore 1.3.0!

Answer (score 1):

**Require.js** is the best alternative in my opinion, since it includes an **optimizer** (minification and concatenation) and allows you to **decouple** your Backbone code into modules.

If you are confused on how to integrate Require.js with the latest versions of Backbone.js and Underscore.js, check out the boilerplate code I created on github.  Keep in mind that I am using **lodash** by John-David Dalton instead of **underscore** because lodash provides better performance and a custom build process.  I am also using the **Shim** configuration that Require.js 2.0 provided to make non-AMD compatible scripts, like Backbone, AMD/Require.js compatible.

https://github.com/gfranko/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried labjs or headjs?

http://labjs.com/

http://headjs.com

Ah, theres the yepnope too!

http://yepnopejs.com/

Comment: Thank u Ricardo! i am giving a try actually to labjs. I will mail back soon about my experience.