# Require.js loading Backbone views in order

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm having issues loading a collection of Backbone Views with RequireJS - as they aren't loading in the correct order.

Below is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve - a page loops through a collection of widgets, and, using its 'template' attribute, get its Backbone View. Its crucial that these are displayed in order, and they are currently being displayed in random order.

**page.js**

```
collection.each(function(widget) {
    require(['order!views/widgets/' + widget.get('template')], function(WidgetView) {
        WidgetView.render();
    })
}
```

**widgets/widgetView.js (generic view)**

```
define(['underscore','backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
    var WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            // .. show view
        }
    });
   return WidgetView;
});
```

I'm aware of the order! plugin for RequireJS, but it doesn't seem to be doing its job. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs I think it is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, issuing multiple `require` calls will fetch the dependencies in asynchronous mode. You probably need to build an array of the views and only then require them. For example,

```
var widgets=[];
collection.each(function(widget) {
    widgets.push('order!views/widgets/' + widget.get('template'));
});

require(widgets, function() {
    var viewclass, view;
    for (var i=0, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
        viewclass=arguments[i];
        view=new viewclass();
        view.render();
    }   
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, it seems that I'm getting an error calling 'arguments', with the error being 'Object function (){a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'render'.

Comment: @crawf My example lacked the instantiation of the view. Updated my answer, it should work now

Comment: Doh! I should have known that..That worked a treat by the way - thanks so much for your help!