# Bootstrap - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, shim

I'm using jquery, backbonejs, underscorejs and bootstrap for my company project. Sometimes I got this error in chrome.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

My shim is like this in my main.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
    backboneeventbinder: 'libs/backbone.eventbinder.min',
    bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap',
    jquerytablesorter: 'libs/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter',
    tablesorter: 'libs/tablesorter/tables',
    ajaxupload: 'libs/ajax-upload',
    templates: '../templates'
},
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
}
});
 require(['app', ], function(App) {
  App.initialize();
});
```

I already insert .noConflict() for jquery, underscorejs and backbonejs.

My app.js

```
// Filename: app.js
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backboneeventbinder', 'bootstrap', 'ajaxupload', 'router', // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Bootstrap, Backboneeventbinder, Ajaxupload, Router) {
    $.noConflict();
    _.noConflict();
    Backbone.noConflict();
    var initialize = function() {
            Router.initialize();
        };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

This is screenshot from my chrome
[image]

Its kind like related to bootstrap.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How to use 'noConflict'?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11184070/122005) may perhaps be useful

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You need to load jquery first before bootstrap.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap',
        jquerytablesorter: 'libs/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter',
        tablesorter: 'libs/tablesorter/tables',
        ajaxupload: 'libs/ajax-upload',
        templates: '../templates'
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jquerytablesorter': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'tablesorter': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'ajaxupload': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
    }
});
require(['app', ], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

Works like charm! quick and easy fix.

Comment: True you need to load the jquery first :D

Comment: If you want to use Bootstrap without Jquery, you still can. Bootstrap 5 doesn't require Jquery any longer.

Answer (score 10):

My way is importing the jquery library.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

To solve this problem just call jQuery file before the bootstrap file

Answer (score 9):

solve this issue for angular

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Import jquery first before bootstrap:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Call .noConflict() to restore JQuery reference.

jQuery.noConflict(); OR  $.noConflict();

//Do something with jQuery.

jQuery( "div.class" ).hide(); OR $( "div.class" ).show();
```

Comment: you should specify when to call `noConflict()`: just after including jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem even jquery was added firs but solved it by adding first the jquery synchronously -deleting asynch tag- then bootsrap.

Note: I added `async` to my jquery tag to load it asynchronously and faced this error so then I changed this:

```
<script async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now my jquery is loading synchronously and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I went back to jquery-2.2.4.min.js and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Firefox showed me this error but in chrome everything was OK.
then after a google search, i used google cdn for jquery in index.html instead of loading local js file and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I changed all 3 links to other versions of bootstrap and got off from that error. I changed 4.5 to 4.6