# Require.js + TypeError: Backbone is undefined after optimization

Tags: javascript, scala, backbone.js, playframework, requirejs

Backbone app works fine pre-optimized.  After using r.js (with almond),  I succesfully generate a single output file that always seems to throw the 'TypeError: Backbone is undefined' error in the module immediately following backbone.

For example, when the output from r.js looks like this:

```
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/almond.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/underscore.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/backbone.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_m.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_c.js
/consumer/public/javascripts/vendor/play-mustache.js
...
/consumer/public/javascripts/main.js
```

Upon loading the optimized file in the browser, the error above will be thrown in the 'prop_m.js' module when referencing Backbone.  Using require 2.0.5, Backbone 0.9.2, and almond 0.1.4.  Thanks in advance for any help.

PS:  build.js looks like this:

```
    ({
    baseUrl:   "./",
    mainConfigFile: "main.js",
    paths: {
    'almond': 'vendor/almond',

        // need a path to the cs-compiled .js file
        'app' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/app',
        'mnp/router' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/router',
        'mnp/search_form_v' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/search_form_v',
        'mnp/prop_c' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_c',
        'mnp/prop_m' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_m',
        'mnp/prop_list_v' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_list_v',
        'mnp/prop_item_v' : '../../target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/rjs/src/mnp/prop_item_v'
    },


    /*not compatible with modules*/
    name: 'vendor/almond',
    include: ["main"],

    out: "dist/app.js",
    /*not compatible with modules*/

    keepBuildDir: false,

    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    optimize: "none", 
    wrap: {
        start: "(function(global, define) {\n"+
           // check for amd loader on global namespace
            "  var globalDefine = global.define;\n",

        end:   "  var library = require('main');\n"+
            "  if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {\n"+
            // export library for node
            "    module.exports = library;\n"+
            "  } else if(globalDefine) {\n"+
            // define library for global amd loader that is already present
            "    (function (define) {\n"+
            "      define(function () { return library; });\n"+
            "    }(globalDefine));\n"+
            "  } else {\n"+
            // define library on global namespace for inline script loading
            "    global['main'] = library;\n"+
            "  }\n"+
            "}(this));\n"
    }


})`
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW:  If anyone runs into this issue...using the amd versions of backbone and underscore seemed to solve things.  ie. the amd-versions worked and the shim didn't

[Loading Backbone and Underscore using RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I forgot to include my `shim`s. I solved it by setting the `mainConfigFile` to my `main.js` file in the build config, e.g. as shown here: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use `inlineText: true` to make sure that backbone is in your compiled `.js` file

furthermore, to avoid having to keep an eye on 2 objects storing the paths, I would recommend something like `mainConfigFile: "main.js"` - works like a charm ;)
EDIT: why do you set a `mainConfigFile` option *and* the paths?

Comment: Thanks, tried adding inlineText: true with no luck...I have both the mainConfig and paths set in build.js because I am using the Scala Play framework which puts compiled coffeescript into a 'managed_resources' directory outside of the baseUrl. So, I use the mainConfig file to set the vendor paths (and shim) in only one place, but use the paths in build.js to override and set the actual physical locations of the play-compiled coffeescript (in managed_resources).  But maybe this is the wrong approach?...

Comment: sry, I'm not familiar with coffeescript :/
but maybe you are loading backbone, but forgot to pass it as parameter (at least the error appears caused by something like this)