# Using require.js with Twitter Boostrap API and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

Regarding this entry [Loading Backbone and Underscore using RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs/8156341#8156341) it is quite clear to me how do I configure `Backbone`-specific scripts and `JQuery`.

But how do I:

- configure `Twitter bootstrap.js`?
- what about `json2.js`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what you learned about the path config option, you should also review the shim config option http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim.

Many plugins are not AMD ready so you have two options. Either configure it as a shim (suitable for most plugins), or write your own adapters like the efforts at https://github.com/amdjs

Simple example:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'], // no exports
        'underscore': { exports: '_' }, // no dependencies
        'backbone.layoutmanager': {
            deps: ['backbone']
            exports: 'Backbone.LayoutManager'
        } // a mix of exports and dependencies
     }
});
```

For something like json2 which has no dependencies and only activates if the browser has no native implementation, you can simply list it as a dependency of your main application's require without a wrapper / shim.