# What is the purpose of config and shim in RequireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to use requireJs with knockout in my mvc4 project . But when i started learning require js i found following code at many places .

```
requirejs.config({
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }

    }
  });
```

I need to know why this config block is use . What is shim inside the config and why we use it , what are the benefits .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading backbone and underscore using requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"shim: Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization for older, traditional "browser globals" scripts that do not use define() to declare the dependencies and set a module value."

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Meaning: backbone does not support requirejs out of the box, hence you have to define the dependencies by yourself.