# RequireJS - why should i shim libs like jquery, backbone etc

Tags: backbone.js, ember.js, requirejs

I saw lot posts and articles in this area. Some of them are,
[Developing Modular Backbonejs Applications](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#modular-development)
[TodoMVC with requireJS](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/main.js)
[Stack Overflow post with most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs)

So no problem for me to modularize jquery, backbonejs and other libraries. My questions is why should i do it? Because on each js file we are going to use jquery and backbonejs and adding this below code on each file seems extra burden to me.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'myFile1', 'myFile1'
], function ($, _, Backbone, module1, module2) {
```

Why should i not include them directly into html file before including requireJS like below?

```
<script src="../lib/client/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/client/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/client/backbone.js"></script>
<script data-main="client/main" src="../lib/client/require.js"></script>
```

In this case, i don't need to define jquery or backbonejs on every js file. I can modularize my own js files alone, like below.

```
define([
    'myFile1', 'myFile1'
], function (module1, module2) {
```

What are the disadvantage by this method? Is this right approach? Did i break any requirejs rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We shim because modules like jQuery and Backbone do not work in the RequireJS model .There is no `define(` statement defining them so they must be shimmed to work like and with real Require modules directly.

Yes, what you said (just dumping them in the global namespace) works, you're not breaking any 'rules'. When you add a script tag all it does is dump the code in the global namespace - so all your modules will, in fact have access to Backbone and jQuery in the above example.

However it has three disadvantages:

- One of the thing we gain with Require is that our dependencies are **explicit** , every time a module needs something we know that - so our dependency management is a lot clearer (We *know* what modules depend on jQuery and what don't for example - so we know which are safe to use in a new project without jQuery).
- Another thing is that we stay consistent across our code, we keep declaring every dependency exactly the same way and using it in exactly the same way. RequireJS shims let us keep acting like that's what's done with libraries like jQuery or Backbone.
- Because of the implicit dependencies, if you ever want to reuse your code - including jQuery *after* your RequireJS modules will be a run time error which is not always trivial to understand, unlike Require which would tell you that it can't load the module jQuery (and not something like $ is not defined, or even worse "[Object object] is not a function" or something like that.

Comment: Another practical problem with HTML imports is that they must be repeated for each HTML file using a JS feature (implemented by a set of JS files). This duplication of concerns is painful to maintain.

Comment: one glad thing is, you confirmed, i'm not breaking any rules. Thanks for that. But for me, in this case, i am seeing jquery and backbone like bootstrap. There is no mean to shim bootstrap. My project should definitely need jquery, backbone to successfully run.

Comment: For me, i feel pain to define jquery, underscore, backbone etc on each file. And when i look at modules with them, i feel, oh man..i know you need jquery, underscore, backbone, what else do you need? :)